# dateparser in python returns unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x, dateparser

```
import dateparser

to_parse = '20210126231003'
parsed = dateparser.parse(to_parse, date_formats=['%Y%m%d%H%M%s'])

print(to_parse)
print(parsed)
```

I am expecting it to resolve to Jan 26 2021...
but it instead resolved to some date in 2034.

```
20210126231003
2034-01-16 03:23:43
```

I am curious on why this is happening. Is my understanding for the parser's functioning wrong?

Comment: The format specifier for seconds is an uppercase `S`: `date_formats=['%Y%m%d%H%M%S']`

Comment: you are correct. so dumb of me. Wish I could give you points for it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the format specifier for second was wrong. it should had been %S.

Closing the question.